# Why is this simple line of PHP code causing an error in JS

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

The code below prints an error in console says `unexpected token '<'`

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<div id="e">hi</div>
<script>
        // var commentId= "<?php echo $comment_id; ?>";
$(function(){
    $("#e").click(function(){
        alert("hi");
    })
})
</script>
```

So I tried:

```
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"> </script>
    <div id="e">hi</div>
    <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#e").click(function(){
            alert("hi");
        })
    })
    </script>
```

It works. But I don't understand why the comment-out part below would affect the javascript running.

```
// var commentId= "<?php echo $comment_id; ?>";
```

Comment: `$comment_id` apparently contains a `<`. Use `htmlspecialchars` to escape it, the error should go away.

Comment: You do realise you can't pass variables from php to js like this right?

Comment: @BenMansley Of course you can. The server side doesn't care if the text is being output as HTML or JavaScript. For example: http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/vsfb-gy0a . To the OP, have you looked at the HTML that was generated to see if you can see what caused the error in the console?

Answer (score 2):

Derek,

The core of your issue, besides what's being stated here is that you have used // to comment out your javascript line, however, that does not stop the execution of `<?php echo $comment_id; ?>`.

So whatever value is in $comment_id is still being echo'd out to the browser. This is sometimes confusing when your using both javascript with embedded php variables. Remember, the php statement is evaluated and executed on the server, the javascript is not executed until script exists in the browswer.

So if you wanted to be really verbose about the whole line being commented out you could write :

```
// var commentId= "`<?php //echo $comment_id; ?>`";
```

At least in theory...I've not actually tested that.

Comment: Why is Javascript complaining about a `<` character in a JS comment? Why does anything in the comment matter?

Comment: @Barmar: JavaScript isn't. Browser is. Browsers intensely dislike people trying to confuse the HTML parsing process by introducing things that look like tags.

Comment: @Amadan I just created a test page with a comment saying `Is a<b` in the script, Chrome didn't complain.

Answer (score 0):

In contradiction to my comment, this is actually a better way:

```
var commentId = <?php echo json_encode($comment_id); ?>;
```

`json_encode` actually is capable of turning any of the types JSON can handle into JavaScript-safe version of it - numbers, strings, arrays, booleans, nulls.